# Conditional formatting for Month

Tags: excel

Need help doing conditional formatting.
I have months from January,February,March...December in A1:A12. I need to do conditional formatting so that "May" get highlighted. Tried Month(Today()) but no luck.

Comment: Try the following formula in conditional formatting =MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH($E7)

Comment: The above formula will work, If the date is formatted as January.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compare the month name of today to whatever is in the range you are conditionally formatting. `=Month(Today())` will return `5` which is not equal to `May` so you get no match.

Instead use formula `=Text()` to format `Today()` as `"MMMM"` which is the full month name of a date:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(), "MMMM")
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it!

Comment: @JNevill works the same for Days as well, just replace MMM with DDDD. Thanks for sorting my issue!